# How to pre-select radio button when using two-way binding in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to fetch some radio inputs and one of them has to be preselected.

Following is the code:

```
<div class='form-group que-box' *ngFor="let option of options">
     <input type='radio' id="{{option.optionId}}" name="radio" [(ngModel)]="optionSelected" value='{{option.optionId}}'>
     <label for='{{option.optionId}}'><span class="que">{{option.text}}</span></label>
 </div>
```

But the button doesn't get preselected.I tried conditionally putting `checked` attribute there but that also doesn't help.The Html is rendered with the `checked` attribute but still the option doesn't get preselected.I have also checked that `optionSelected` always contain desirable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `optionSelected` to the value of the option you want to select should work, something like:

```
this.optionSelected = option[0].optionId;
```

If `optionId` is a number or anything else than a string, then setting the value using [interpolation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation) (`value='{{ option.optionId }}'`) will not work, as it will be evaluated as string, so it will not match `optionSelected` when checked using [strict equality (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?v=control#Identity_strict_equality_()), which Angular is using under the hood.

A quick fix would be to force `optionSelected` to be a string as well:

```
this.optionSelected = option[0].optionId + '';
```

The correct way to fix this is by using [data binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax) to set the `value` attribute.

**In  Angular (Angular 2 and 4):**

```
[value]="optionSelected"
```

**In AngularJS (Angular 1):**

```
ng-value="optionSelected"
```

Comment: I have done something similar. The optionSelected contains valid value in my code.

Comment: @sudheer-singh When you use `value` instead of `ng-value`, the value will always be interpreted as a string. Probably `this.optionSelected = option[0].optionId + '';` will work. If you don't want to do this, then use `ng-value` in your HTML instead.

Comment: changing `value` to `[value]` worked. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @sudheer-singh Updated the answer to reflect what we discussed in the comments and to point out the solution for both AngularJS and Angular.